# Moving all Elements in a std::vector not working as expected

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to move the whole vector to another variable.
The following code block does not compile.
I thought that the call to `std::move` would force to use the Move-Constructor. Instead it seems like std::vector is using the Copy-Constructor that is deleted.

What's wrong here? How can I move all elements without copying them?

```
#include <vector>

class TheClass {
public:
  TheClass(const TheClass&) = delete;
  TheClass(TheClass&&) = default;
};

void fun2(const std::vector<TheClass> data) {
  std::vector<TheClass> a = std::move(data);
  a.size();
}
```

leads to:

```
clang++ -o /cplayground/cplayground /cplayground/code.cpp -I/cplayground/include -L/cplayground/lib -std=c++20 -O0 -Wall -no-pie -lm -pthread
In file included from /cplayground/code.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/vector:66:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:137:7: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_constructible<TheClass, const TheClass &>::value' "result type must be constructible from value type of input range"
      static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
      ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:325:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::uninitialized_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const TheClass *, std::vector<TheClass, std::allocator<TheClass> > >, TheClass *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:558:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const TheClass *, std::vector<TheClass, std::allocator<TheClass> > >, TheClass *, TheClass>' requested here
          std::__uninitialized_copy_a(__x.begin(), __x.end(),
               ^
/cplayground/code.cpp:10:29: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<TheClass, std::allocator<TheClass> >::vector' requested here
  std::vector<TheClass> a = std::move(data);
                            ^
In file included from /cplayground/code.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/vector:62:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_algo.h:62:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_construct.h:109:38: error: call to deleted constructor of 'TheClass'
    { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                                     ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:91:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Construct<TheClass, const TheClass &>' requested here
                std::_Construct(std::__addressof(*__cur), *__first);
                     ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:150:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const TheClass *, std::vector<TheClass, std::allocator<TheClass> > >, TheClass *>' requested here
        __uninit_copy(__first, __last, __result);
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:325:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::uninitialized_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const TheClass *, std::vector<TheClass, std::allocator<TheClass> > >, TheClass *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:558:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const TheClass *, std::vector<TheClass, std::allocator<TheClass> > >, TheClass *, TheClass>' requested here
          std::__uninitialized_copy_a(__x.begin(), __x.end(),
               ^
/cplayground/code.cpp:10:29: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<TheClass, std::allocator<TheClass> >::vector' requested here
  std::vector<TheClass> a = std::move(data);
                            ^
/cplayground/code.cpp:5:3: note: 'TheClass' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  TheClass(const TheClass&) = delete;
  ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: In your function, `data` is `const` and moving is a mutable operation, so they can't mix.

Comment: Since the type of data is `const std::vector<TheClass>`, the return type of `std::move(data)` will be `const std::vector<TheClass>&&`, which invokes the copy constructor instead of the move constructor.

Comment: Moving a `std::vector` will not use any constructor of the element type anyway. It would behave exactly the same whether or not the move/copy constructors are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `move` something that is `const` (I mean, you can call `std::move` on it, but it won't allow you to move things). Remove that qualifier and (maybe) pass a rvalue reference:

```cpp
void fun2(std::vector<TheClass>&& data)
{
    std::vector<TheClass> a = std::move(data);
    a.size();
}
```

Then :

```
std::vector<TheClass> vec;
fun2(std::move(vec));
```

Note that you *may* omit that `&&`(see https://godbolt.org/z/5M1f4j66r).

Comment: But aren't the elements then copied when calling `fun2({})`?

Comment: I'd argue that any recent compiler would choose copy elision in that case, unless you try to do `fun2(std::move(std::vector<TheClass>{}));` which prevents it. That may even be required actually (but not sure about that).

Comment: @emcell As another user said in comments, moving a vector cannot involve moving or copying elements, it is required to have [constant complexity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). It's usually as simple as reassigning few pointers.